# Probability of an event occuring $n$ times, given that it can occur $n$ times or does not occur at all.

Tags: probability, optimization

Suppose you have an event whose probability is $\rho$. This event either does not occur at all or occurs $n$ times, because when it occurs once, all the others occurrences are linked to the first.

What's the probability that the event occurs ?

Here is the context for this question:
I am desgining an algorithm with constrained preferential attachment. I have a set of items $E=\{1,\dots,m\}$ and for every pair of item $(i,j)$, I have a score $w_{ij}$ that captures the preference of $i$ to be attached to $j$.
Then, I have a set of pairs of items $M\subset E \times E$, and if $(i,j) \in M$, then $i$ must be attached to $j$.
So, if $i\sim j \sim k$, then $i\sim k$, obviously, as this property is transitive.
The event I was talking about at the beginning is "the constraint $(i,j)\in M$ is satisfied". Now, there may be some errors in $M$, therefore the likelihood of the correctness of any item in $M$ is $\rho$.
I would like to increase $w_{ij}$ by some factor depending on the number of satisfied must-link, in order to reward that behavior.

Since, satisfying $10$ must-links is better than satisfying just $1$,what should be the factor of increase ?

My guess is $1+(1-(1-\rho)^n)$.

What do you guys think ?

Comment: That number exceeds $1$.  I'm not entirely clear on the question, but why isn't the answer $\rho$?  You start by saying you "have an event with probability $\rho$" so why isn't the probability of the event $\rho$?

Comment: That's what I was wondering aswell, but according to my experiments so far, my initial guess gives the best results. So, why is it not just $\rho$ ? Because, as I said, satisfying $10$ constraints is better than satisfying $1$. And if I increased $w_{ij}$ by a factor of $1+\rho$, that would not capture the count of satisfied constraints.

Comment: As I say, I can't really follow the algorithm part (no idea what a "constrained preferential attachment" is, for example.  But your formula can't yield a probability as it exceeds $1$.  Here's how I understand the question (by analogy):  You have a bag containing five coins.  four of these are normal but one has a star on each side.  You draw randomly from the bag and toss $100$ times (sticking with the coin you drew first).  So...you either see $0$ stars or $100$.  The probability that you see $100$ is the probability that you got the star coin, which in this case is $\frac 15$.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "you have an event whose probability is $\rho$"?  How does that differ from "the probability that the event occurs."?  In my experience, confusion in probability usually comes out of unclear phrasing.   So...what exactly does $\rho$ mean?

Comment: If the probability that some event $A$ occurs is $\rho\in[0,1]$ then the probability that it occurs is $\rho$, no question about that. – Talking about $n$ times refers to some other probability space and some other, more complicated, event.